# A double counting proof of a sum identity

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove the following identity combinatorialy
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(2n)!}{(k!)^2((n-k)!)^2}={2n \choose n}^2$$
The interpretation I have of the right side is that it was a $n \times n$ lattice walk from (0,0) to (n,n) and then from (n,n) back to (0,0) but I am unable to make sense of the LHS like this

I would appreciate any help and suggestions regarding my problem

Comment: @runway44 That is a completely different identity.

Comment: Now I see the difference. This identity is $\binom{2n}{n}$ times $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sides answer the question

> How many ways are there to make a walk of length $2n$ in the plane which starts where it ends, and where each step is one unit either up, down, left or right?

On the one hand, suppose that $k$ of the steps of the walk are up steps. This means there must also be $k$ down steps to restore the $y$ displacement to zero. Since the left and right steps must balance as well, there are then $n-k$ left steps and $n-k$ right steps. The number of ways to choose an ordering for these steps is $(2n)!/(k!\cdot k! \cdot (n-k)!\cdot (n-k)!)$, which is then summed over $k$.

On the other hand, define the vectors
$$
v=(\tfrac12,\tfrac12),\qquad w=(\tfrac12,-\tfrac12)
$$
Note that the four vectors of the form
$$
\pm v\pm w
$$
are exactly the four unit vectors pointing up, down, left and right. Therefore, you can uniquely determine a walk of length $2n$ in the plane as follows:

- Choose a sequence $s$ of length $2n$, where $n$ of the entries are $+v$ and $n$ are $-v$. This can be done in $\binom{2n}n$ ways.
- Choose a sequence $t$ of length $2n$, where $n$ of the entries are $+w$ and $n$ are $-w$. This can be done in $\binom{2n}n$ ways.
- Finally, form a walk of length $2n$, where the $i^\text{th}$ step of the walk is the vector sum of the $i^\text{th}$ elements of the $s$ and $t$ sequences.

Answer (score 3):

LHS is $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} \cdot \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{k! (n - k)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2$$

RHS is $$\binom{2n}{n}^2$$

So, we only need to prove $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof) is a combinatorial proof for Vandermonde's Identity

There is no need of multiplication either. We can just prove $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}^2$$

The RHS counts the ordered pair of paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, n)$. The paths may be identical.

Let's look at LHS.

First, we select the first path. $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways.

Now by iterating on $k$, we are counting the ordered pair of paths with $k$ right (or, analogous up) moves in the first $n$ moves. The other part then find the number of ways to pick $n - k$ positions for the right (or up) moves in the second half. The rest are up (or right) moves.

$$LHS = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n - k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer I would like to know if we can like show a bijection to prove the identity (2n)!/((k!)^2(n-k)!^2)=C(2n,n)*C(n,k)^2

Comment: Regarding “There is no need for cancellation” — your first argument didn’t use cancellation anyway.  Cancellation is implications like “$ab = ac \Rightarrow b = c$”; what you used was the converse, “$b = c \Rightarrow ab = ac$”, which follows just from laws of equality.

Comment: @user940158 $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2((n - k)!)^2}$ represents the number of ways to arrange $k$ A, $k$ B, $n - k$ C, $n - k$ D. $\binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{k}$ also finds the same thing, by first picking $n$ spots for $A$ and $C$ (their sum is $n$), then out of $n$ spots, pick $k$ for $A$ (rest will be $C$). Out of the remaining $n$ spots, pick $k$ for $B$ (rest will be $D$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combinatorial interpretation I came up with. The LHS counts how many strings of length $2n$ with 4 letters A,B,C,D have $k$ A's, $k$ B's, $n-k$ C's, and $n-k$ D's (multinomial coefficient). The RHS counts the square of the number of strings of length $2n$ with 2 letters, $n$ A's and $n$ B's. Taking two strings with $n$ A's and $n$ B's, for example AAABBB and ABABAB, then mapping each pair of letters from both strings to one of four new letters, gives $k$ AA's, $n-k$ AB's, $k$ BB's, and $n-k$ BA's.